# Provide extra context to all views

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm putting together a project management website for my team using django. My base template includes a sidebar menu which contains a list of all projects and users, linking to a `DetailView` for that user or project, respectively.

My problem is that I need to provide the `User` and `Project` models to every view so that I can render that sidebar. I know how to [add extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context); the problem is that I feel like I'm violating DRY by modifying the context at each level. Is it possible to simply redefine the base `TemplateClass` so that all child classes—`ListView`, `DetailView`, etc.—contain the modified context?

On a related note, if this is a terrible way to set up the project, let me know that as well.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use the [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

`myapp/context_processors.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import Project

def users_and_projects(request):
    return {'all_users': User.objects.all(),
            'all_projects': Project.objects.all()}
```

And then add this processor to the [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting for Django version < 1.8:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'myapp.context_processors.users_and_projects',
)
```

And for Django version >= 1.8 add it to the `context_processors` list in the `OPTIONS` of the `TEMPLATES` setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'myapp.context_processors.users_and_projects',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Context processor will run for ALL your requests.  If your want to run these queries only for views which use the `base.html` rendering then the other possible solution is the [custom assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags):

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_all_users():
    return User.objects.all()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_all_projects():
    return Project.objects.all()
```

And the in your `base.html` template:

```
{% load mytags %}

{% get_all_users as all_users %}
<ul>
{% for u in all_users %}
    <li><a href="{{ u.get_absolute_url }}">{{ u }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% get_all_projects as all_projects %}
<ul>
{% for p in all_projects %}
    <li><a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">{{ p }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks! Just for added completeness: [link to the django docs discussing writing your own template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I changed the first link in the answer.

Comment: Since Django 1.8, context processors are added to the [TEMPLATES setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#templates) ```TEMPLATES = [{
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [...]
    }
}]```

Comment: As of Django 1.9, [assignment_tag is deprecated and needs to be replaced with `simple_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.9/#features-deprecated-in-1-9). So, instead of `@register.assignment_tag` You should use `@register.simple_tag`.

Comment: Why add it to my app, is there a way to add it to all apps?

Comment: @DerekPK it will work for all apps in your project, it is written in `myapp` because well the code has to live _somewhere_ right?