# Trouble with Django importing random list in base template using ´super´. What is the alternative to my work-around?

Tags: django, super

Update: Included a small adjustment thanks to replies, see below.

I'm trying to load an random list in the title of my webpage (base template). I was able to get this running using Super. However, at this point this is done for every view.

This seems illogical. As an amateur I have trouble finding out if this is true and/or if I am even right (I have some trouble interpreting the technical descriptions..).

Could someone push me in the right direction?

List generation:

```
def generatetraits():
    traits = ["trait1", "trait2", "trait3", "trait4", "trait5", "trait6",         
    "trait7", "trait8", "trait9", "trait10", "trait11"]
    random.shuffle(traits)
    traitlist = ""

    for i in range(0, 3):
        if (i == 0) or (i == 1):
            traitlist = traitlist + (traits[i] + " | ")
        else:
            traitlist = traitlist + (traits[i] + " ")

    return traitlist
```

SomeView example:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

    traitlist = generatetraits()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'traits': self.traitlist})
        return context
```

Base template implementation:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>Name</h1>
     <p> {{traits}} </p>
</div>
```

All pages/views are extended from the base. This makes it logical to me (as amateur;)) that it is just wrong to do this for every view.

Update:

Context call has been shortend to:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return {'traits': generatetraits()}
```

Comment: Do you want it to appear on every page or only on the about.html page?

Comment: BTW: Your `for i in range(0, 3):` block (up to/ excluding the return stmt) can be rewritten as `' | '.join(traitlist[:3])`.

Comment: I would like it to appear on every page. Right now the solution is repeating the above for every view. Thanks for the tip b.t.w.!:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provide extra context to all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533854/provide-extra-context-to-all-views)

Comment: @solarissmoke, I'm not sure it is duplicate. However it got the ball rolling in shortening the code. Am I correct in understanding the context HAS to be called for every view and cannot be called only for the base template from which every view extends?

Comment: You could have an abstract BaseView (in addition to the base template) that adds general context to the views, and your actual views would extend from it. Django's generic views do that, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was setting up a context processor as pointed out by @solarissmoke.

This processor ended up as:

```
def headertaggen(request):
    traits = ["trait1", "trait2", "trait3", "trait4", "trait5", "trait6"]
    random.shuffle(traits)

    return {'traits': ' | '.join(traits[:3:])}
```

The key 'traits' is than called in the base template which is populated by all other templates.

Thanks for the help everyone!