# Call model in base html file django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

Im trying to find out how to call one of my models in my base html file that extends to my other template html files in order to implement viewing of cart items in the navbar which is in my base.html file. normally i would have used context data to call models in my views (I am using Class Based Views) but this is not possible with base.html file

this is the code that would be used to if it was a template with a view

```
{% for item in orderitems %}
<div class="ps-product__thumbnail">
  <a href="#"> 
     <img src="img/products/clothing/7.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="ps-product__content">
  <a class="ps-product__remove" href="#">
    <i class="icon-cross"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="product-default.html">MVMTH Classical Leather Watch InBlack</a>
  <p><strong>Sold by:</strong> YOUNG SHOP</p><small>1 x $59.99</small>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i didnt create a model in a html file i called its objects in a forloop tag within the template and thats an example of what i would like to do in base.html

Comment: i dont think you understood the context in which im using base.html  , base.html is the file i extend to other templates in my project meaning it has no view it uses templates' views to which it is extended and is rendered as a part of them

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217973/discussion-between-crimsonpython24-and-jordan-rob).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide extra context to all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533854/provide-extra-context-to-all-views)

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for taking so long to get things clear)

Since you still need to pass in context data, I will suggest using the extending technique. For example:

```py
# views.py
# doesn't have to be same, they're just examples

class OrderBaseView(ListView):
    template_name = "order_base.html"
    # add models, authentication, whatever

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # handle the context data
        return context


# this class extends the view above, and therefore
# will extend the get_context_data method.
class NextLevelView(OrderBaseView):
    template_name = "next_level.html"
    # your other handles here


# you can re-inherit the get_context_data call!
class AnotherView(OrderBaseView):
    # more custom handles here
```

```html
<!-- order_base.html -->
<!-- the code that you provided above -->
```

```html
<!-- next_level.html -->
<!-- you can do whatever you want here first -->
{% include "order_base.html" %}
```

Do re-check the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template syntax.

So then you will have the context data inside a `base.html` (just different names as it's not a *universal* base HTML) but then you can reuse it in multiple places and the context will get in if you handled it correctly.

**Bonus**

Let's say your code gets more complicated and needs to handle more context. Here's what you should do:

```py
# views.py
class OrderBaseView(ListView):
    # ...
    def get_context_data_basic(self, **kwargs):
        # handle basic context
        return context


class NextLevelView(OrderBaseView):
    # ...

    # this method MUST be in this name because
    # Django will look for it automatically. The
    # basic handles are given a different name
    # to prevent ambiguities.
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        # calls parent context data view
        # remember to transfer the data to the main context
        # be careful of name overlaps
        temp = get_context_data_basic(self, **kwargs)
        context = temp.copy()

        # your other handles here
        # ...

        return context
```