# Django Form Neither Shows Up nor Is It Integrated in The HTML

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a django form that works as a search bar, i've been following the tutorial i'm watching to the T, but for some reason when i run the code the form isn't there, and there's no trace of it in the HTML when i inspect it, it's as if i wrote nothing at all. below is the code i wrote in views.py, layout.html (& also entry.html although it's empty for now) and the path in urls.py . It should be noted that this is the first time i work with django and so far it's been a bit confusing so please do check the code out and point out any and all bug(s). Thank You.

**Views.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render

class searchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()

def search(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "form": searchForm()
    })
```

**layout.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
            <h2>Wiki</h2>
            <form action="{% url 'wiki:search' %}" method="post">
                {{ form }}
            </form>
            <div>
                <a href="{% url 'wiki:index' %}">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                Create New Page
            </div>
            <div>
                Random Page
            </div>
            {% block nav %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**entry.html**

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "wiki"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:title>", views.title, name="title"),
    path("<str:query>", views.search, name="search")
]
```

Comment: In the post, you have rendered the form in `layout.html` but in the code the template file you are using is `entry.html`. Could it be causing this problem?

Comment: I doubt it, because entry.html is an extention of layout.html, this search bar is supposed to exist in all webpages of the app. so layout.html is the file that should be edited.

Comment: Could you also add the code for `entry.html` where it is extending `layout.html`?

Comment: Done. although it's an empty page so far so it wouldn't be of much help. my problem is with the form that's on the side bar which is written in layout.html (which is a much larger file but the form element is the only relevant part)

Comment: Does `layout.html` also have `{% block body %}`? If yes, is the `form` rendered inside that block?

Comment: Yes it does, but the form is not inside that block no. i will update the layout.html so that it can include all the info you'll need. i can't change where the block body is because it would completely mess up the layout,

Comment: And, which Url are you trying to access when you see that the form is not rendered? I see that the the form is provided from the `search` view so are you trying to access that url?

Comment: i thought about your question for a sec and edited it to render index.html instead (also an extention of layout.html) but the problem persisted, the issue is either in layout.html or views.py. the form just doesn't show up.

Comment: "search bar is supposed to exist in all webpages of the app", well but it appears that you only pass the form into the context in the view named `search`, just because you pass it in one view does not mean it is also passed in _other_ views...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide extra context to all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533854/provide-extra-context-to-all-views)

Comment: It Worked!!! I passed form in every view and there it is! Thank you so much.