# Navbar problem with views context, when using slug or PK. (Django)

Tags: django, navbar, dry, slug, django-context

The slug will only work on `HomeView` if I add it to the `HomeView`s context, but I only want to add it one time, I don't want to add it to every view, but I want it to work on every view.

Is there anyway I can do this?

***app2/models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

***app1/views.py***

```
from app2.models import Model1
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic.list import ListView


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Model1
    ordering = ['-id']
    template_name = 'app1/home.html'
    boolean = False
    model1_slug = 'app2'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            if Model1.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
                self.boolean = True
                user_model1 = Model1.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
                self.model1_slug = user_model1.slug
                
            else:
                self.model1_slug = 'app2'
                self.boolean = False
            context['model1_slug'] = self.model1_slug
            context['boolean'] = self.boolean
        return context
```

***includes/navbar.html***

```
            {% if boolean == False %}
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'start-model1' %}">Start Model1</a></li>
            {% elif boolean == True  %}
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'my-model1' model1_slug %}">My Model1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'add-model2' %}">Add model2</a></li>
            {% endif %}
```

The navbar will give nothing if I'm not at the home page.

Comment: I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533854/provide-extra-context-to-all-views?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes it does.

Comment: But you need to delete request, If you get this error **'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'**. So if it is `self.request.user` change it to `self.user`.