# django if else template tag using object from with template tag

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have an if/else statement that determines which button will be displayed in my base.py template.  From doing my research I think I am on the right path, but regardless of if the enddate field is null or populated, the endcast button displays.

model:

```
class Cast(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id')
    startdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartDate')
    enddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='EndDate')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Cast'
        verbose_name_plural = "Cast"
        get_latest_by = "pk"
```

template block:

```
    <div class="top-button-container stickey-top">
        {% with last=Cast.objects.latest %}
            {% if last.enddate %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'caststart' %}">Start Cast</a>
                </button>
            {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cast_end' %}">End Cast</a>
                </button>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
```

views:

```
def caststart(request):
    context ={}
    form = StartCastForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StartCastForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            castid=Cast.objects.last()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("%i/castend" % castid.pk)
    else:
        form = StartCastForm 
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
            return render(request, 'wwdb/casts/caststart.html', {'form':form, 'submitted':submitted, 'id':id})

    context['form']= form

    return render(request, "wwdb/casts/caststart.html", context)

def cast_end(request):
    last = Cast.objects.latest('pk')
    return redirect('castend', id=last.pk)

def castend(request, id):
    context ={}
    obj = get_object_or_404(Cast, id = id)
    form = EndCastForm(request.POST or None, instance = obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cast=Cast.objects.last()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            cast.refresh_from_db()
            cast.endcastcal()
            cast.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/wwdb/casts/%i/castenddetail" % cast.pk)
    context["form"] = form
    return render(request, "wwdb/casts/castend.html", context)
```

I was expecting the "start cast" button to render when the last objects enddate field is populated.  The "end cast" button should render when the enddate field is none. It currently renders the "end cast" button regardless of the last objects enddate field value.

Comment: What does the view that renders this template look like?

Comment: I updated the question to include the views. @jaap3

Comment: Seems that the template is never passed a `Cast` model in the context, so the `Cast.objects.latest` doesn't do anything. You could either pass the `Cast` model in the context, or do the `last` lookup in the view and pass that.

Comment: But this is the base template, so nearly every template loads this template.  Would I need to pass the Cast model in the context for every view associated with a template that will be loading my base.py template? @jaap3

Comment: You might want to look into context processors for that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: Spot on @jaap3 .  Took a little bit of troubleshooting but I got it working.  This feed gave me all the answers I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533854/provide-extra-context-to-all-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I needed add a context processor to resolve this problem.

I created the file myapp/context_processors.py

```
from myapp.models import Cast

def cast_context(request):
    return {'last': Cast.objects.last()}
```

in my base.py template:

```
<div class="top-button-container stickey-top">
    {% if last.enddate %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'caststart' %}">Start Cast</a>
        </button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cast_end' %}">End Cast</a>
        </button>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'context_processors.cast_context',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors.cast_context',
        },
    },
]
```